# How to use (liven up) certain GIT projects in IntelliJ?

Tags: git, intellij-idea, import

I have downloaded some project via GIT, say, h2database. I used File - New - Project From Version Control - GIT, then

[image]

Then I have all files downloaded successfully but the project appeared is "dead". No symbols are recognized, no building works etc.

What does it lack to work?

How to add "java nature" or something to the project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is project specific. You need to set up a project after cloning it.

In your case, when you need h2, you probably want to follow this documentation: http://www.h2database.com/html/build.html#using_eclipse (most things should work the same in IntelliJ).

Comment: So, I can't do staying in IntelliJ here? I need separately (1) git, (2) run script, (3) import existing, right?

Comment: Yes, I think so. You can run the script in IntelliJ embedded terminal though ;) But still, it cannot be done in one step IMHO.